# Yubikey ssh authentication fails with "signing failed for ECDSA-SK"

Tags: ssh, freebsd, ssh-keys, yubikey

I have a Yubikey (Security Key NFC by Yubico) that I'm trying to set up on a Linux machine for SSH authentication in Discoverable keys mode. I've followed [this tutorial](https://developers.yubico.com/SSH/Securing_SSH_with_FIDO2.html) and created the keys with

```
ssh-keygen -t ecdsa-sk -O resident -O application=ssh:YourTextHere -O verify-required
```

After that, the pub key was copied to the destination server, and I can correctly login with

```
ssh -i /root/.ssh/YourTextHere server
```

However, when I try to connect loading the key on an agent, without using the certificate, I get the following error:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ECDSA-SK "" from agent: agent refused operation
root@opnsense: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I load the ssh-agent with

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
```

and add the key from Yubikey with

```
ssh-add -K
```

I can correctly see the loaded key with a

```
ssh-add -L
```

It all points out to a signing problem with the agent, but I'm not sure how to move forward.I've already enabled all the signing algorithms in the destination server.

I'm trying to do the connection from a Debian 12, openssh version OpenSSH_9.2p1.
The destination machine is an freebsd (opnsense firewall), openssh version OpenSSH_9.3p2
Is there something I'm missing?

**EDIT**: **Solution found**, see response from @Ramhound. I had to do an

```
apt-get install ssh-askpass
```

then

```
which ssh-askpass
```

will show you the path of the binary. After that I just need to do

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s; SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ssh-askpass)"
```

and get prompted for your pin and presence. After that connection was successful.

Comment: Why are you trying to load the key without the certificate? How about server logs at the time of the client connection?

Comment: I don't want the certificate to be written down to disk. If I re-generate it with `ssh-keygen -K`, I can authenticate, but not using the agent itself. Logs on the server show a generic `"2023-08-17T18:56:11 Error sshd error: PAM: Authentication error for root from 192.168.0.2"`, nothing useful

Comment: The logs should indicate what authentication mode is being attempted right before the authentication fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`verify-required` requires a way for *`ssh-agent`* to actually prompt for verification (whether it's a "touch" request or a PIN input prompt). The agent protocol does not include any way for it to relay prompts back to the calling program, so `ssh-agent` needs to directly start the `ssh-askpass` prompter.

Make sure a version of `ssh-askpass` is installed (there are a few variants for different desktops, I think) and if necessary, set `SSH_ASKPASS=` to its path so that `ssh-agent` could find it.

Comment: That was it! I'll update the solution on the main post, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `~/.profile` file:

```bash
if [ -S "$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh" ] ; then
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$HOME/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"
        export SSH_AUTH_SOCK
        export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
        gpg-connect-agent updatestartuptty /bye
fi
```